# Dovecot Replication isn't notifying

Tags: ubuntu, dovecot

I have dovecot v2.2.33.2 installed on Ubuntu 18.04.1. I have configured Dovecot replicator the same way I normally do it for HA servers, but for some reason it isn't syncing new emails that come into mx1 to mx2. If I open the email and read it on mx1, it then syncs to mx2. Or if I delete it, same deal.

If on mx2 I write a new email and send, it instantly syncs to mx1.

It's like mx1 isn't sending new notifications to mx2 for new emails, but sync works fine once I open the email.

I have setup replication a few times and never had this issue, not sure where the issue is.

Config on mx1 and 2 are the same, except for the IP of each points to the other of course.

Here is the `dovecot.conf` file:

```
listen = *,[::]
protocols = imap pop3
auth_mechanisms = plain login
disable_plaintext_auth = no
log_timestamp = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S "
mail_privileged_group = vmail
postmaster_address = postmaster@mx1.domain.com
ssl_cert = </etc/postfix/smtpd.cert
ssl_key = </etc/postfix/smtpd.key
ssl_protocols =  !SSLv3
mail_max_userip_connections = 100
passdb {
  args = /etc/dovecot/dovecot-sql.conf
  driver = sql
}
userdb {
  driver = prefetch
}
userdb {
  args = /etc/dovecot/dovecot-sql.conf
  driver = sql
}
plugin {
  quota = dict:user::file:/var/vmail/%d/%n/.quotausage
  sieve=/var/vmail/%d/%n/.sieve
  sieve_max_redirects = 25
}
service auth {
  unix_listener /var/spool/postfix/private/auth {
    group = postfix
    mode = 0660
    user = postfix
  }
  unix_listener auth-userdb {
    group = vmail
    mode = 0600
    user = vmail
  }
  user = root
}
service lmtp {
  unix_listener /var/spool/postfix/private/dovecot-lmtp {
   group = postfix
   mode = 0600
   user = postfix
  }
}
service imap-login {
  client_limit = 1000
  process_limit = 512
}
protocol imap {
  mail_plugins = quota imap_quota
}
protocol pop3 {
  pop3_uidl_format = %08Xu%08Xv
  mail_plugins = quota
}
protocol lda {
postmaster_address = postmaster@mx1.domain.com
  mail_plugins = sieve quota
}
protocol lmtp {
postmaster_address = postmaster@mx1.domain.com
  mail_plugins = quota sieve
}
mail_plugins = $mail_plugins quota

# Enable the replication plugin globally
mail_plugins = $mail_plugins notify replication quota

# Both the client and the server need to have a shared secret
doveadm_password = pass_word

# configure how many dsyncs can be run in parallel (10 by default)
replication_max_conns = 10

service aggregator {
        fifo_listener replication-notify-fifo {
                user = vmail
                mode = 0666
        }

        unix_listener replication-notify {
                user = vmail
                mode = 0666
        }
}

service replicator {
        unix_listener replicator-doveadm {
                mode = 0666
        }
}

service doveadm {
        user = vmail
        inet_listener {
                port = 4711
        }
}

service config {
        unix_listener config {
                user = vmail
        }
}

# use tcp:ip as the dsync target
plugin {
        replication_full_sync_interval = 1 hours
        mail_replica = tcp:0.0.0.0:4711
}

protocol imap {
        mail_plugins = quota imap_quota notify replication
}
```

Also, if I run `doveadm replicator replicate '*'` to force the replication it instantly sends pending emails to mx2. But without it, it won't. During my testing I got it to send to mx2 once automatically, it took about 20 minutes to do.

Since then, it hasn't done it automatically again. Status shows that last sync time just keeps growing and unless I run a force or open the email it doesn't go back to zero.

Answer (score 0):

You forgot the plugins in the protocol blocks:

```
protocol imap {
  mail_plugins = notify replication quota imap_quota
}
protocol pop3 {
  pop3_uidl_format = %08Xu%08Xv
  mail_plugins = notify replication quota
}
```

Once you add them, after your mailbox changes it shows in the replication status:

```
# doveadm replicator status '*'
username               priority fast sync full sync success sync failed
test@xxx.tld           none     00:00:03  00:33:57  00:00:03     -
```

Comment: But I don't have that in my `dovecot.conf` file on an ubuntu 16 server that "IS" working fine.

Comment: Do you have something like `mail_plugins = $mail_plugins quota imap_quota` inside the imap block? If yes, you use the earlier defined plugins in the block as well.

Comment: I tried adding that into those two protocol blocks and still no go.

Comment: look at logs and if there is Permission denied, try this: chown vmail:vmail /var/run/dovecot/replication-notify-fifo